# Casting a uint** to a uint

Tags: c, double-pointer

I have the below code

```
unsigned int headerbytes = 0U;
    headerbytes = (unsigned int*)strtoull(packet_space->header, NULL, 0);

    packetHeader header = deconstructPacketHeader((&headerbytes));
```

packet_space is a char[], basically its a 4byte char array that I want to convert to a unsigned int.  deconstructPacketHeader() takes an unsigned int, but stroutll (With my cast) is returning a double pointer.  basically, how do I get the actual value of the uint (dereference twice) so I can pass it do deconstructPacketHeader() ?

Thanks!

Comment: If `packet_space` is a `char[]`, how can `packet_space->header` be a valid term?

Comment: BTW: I don't know what strange `strtoull()` you have, but the [standard one](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoull) returns a `unsigned long long int`.

Comment: Assigning an `unsigned int *` to `unsigned int`???

Comment: What are the contents of packet_space->header? Does it contain a null-terminated string with the textual representation of a number, or does it contain a four-byte integer obtained by reading from a network stream (or from a file) ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you think too complicated.

Try

```
unsigned long long headerbytes = 0ULL;
headerbytes = strtoull(packet_space->header, NULL, 0);
packetHeader header = deconstructPacketHeader(headerbytes);
```